# XPC test bundle on Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xpc

I have Cocoa application with custom XPC service. I would like to create tests for that XPC, so I created new test bundle for that and created some tests. But when I run those tests (whose doesn't show any error in Xcode), IDE is not able to link them to tested XPC bundle. Of course I set Target Dependency to my XPC bundle but it still doesn't work.

I think that problem will be at **Test host** settings but I'm not good at Xcode configuration. I also studied Apple's tutorial (Daemons and Services Programming Guide) but it doesn't mention testing XPC bundle. Neither their example SandboxedFetch.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this front? I'm also interested in a solution to this problem.

Comment: Debugging of XPC services in Xcode 5 is in a similar state.  Attempts to attach to the XPC process crashes Xcode.  I have filed a bug report for the latter issue and recommend for you to do the same for XPC unit testing integration.

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode 7, I managed to test my XPC by adding it in the *Copy file build phase* of my test target (specifying *XPC Services* for destination.

Comment: Did you figure out how to make the test coverage work under this arrangement?